# How to restrict debug message printed in the application.log file

Tags: log4j

I have a log4j.xml

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
   <appender name="appenderConsole" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

      <appender name="appenderFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
           <param name="File" value="log\\AuditComp.log"/>
           <param name="Append" value="false"/>
            <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
           <param name="MaxFileSize" value="15MB"/>
           <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
           <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
           </layout>
       </appender>
   <root>
    <level value="info"/>
   <!-- <appender-ref ref="appenderConsole" />  --> 
     <appender-ref ref="appenderFile"/>   
  </root>   
</log4j:configuration>
```

I need only Info message present in program code should be printed in log file . But while executing the program it is printing all the message (debug, info , warn). How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this element instead of `Threshold` parameter under `appender` element:

```
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO"/>
    <param name="LevelMax" value="OFF"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: above method did not work . For more information I am using the below method for printing log logger.log(FQCN, UtilConstant.levelObjs[level], formattedMsg, throwable);  where       levelObjs[level]=  {Level.INFO, Level.DEBUG, Level.WARN, Level.ERROR, Level.FATAL, Level.TRACE};